# Magento 2 Override checkout model class

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, overrides

I am working with Magento2, so as per my requirement I need to override the "Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart.php" class, but the cart.php class look like as follow

```
namespace Magento\Checkout\Model;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\CartInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

/**
 * Shopping cart model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @deprecated 
 */
class Cart extends DataObject implements CartInterface {}
```

So, from the above, I am not sure how to override this class.
Kindly share your idea and thoughts it'll help me.

Answer (score 1):

Better option to use plugin instead of override but if you want override then you can manage this by below code:
Your module **di.xml** code will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Cart" />
</config>
```

And **app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Model/Cart.php** code will be:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
{

}
```